# How to pass query results with FK relations(EF) to the View

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am not able to figure out this simple thing in ASP.NET MVC:

I have two tables:

```
  Customer:
    CustomerID
    FirstName
    LastName
    AddressID
    AddressTemporaryID

  Address:
    AddressID
    Street
    City
```

I have my relations(FK) set in DB and trying to use Entity Framework. My navigation properties(FK) are named Addresses and Addresses1. 
I created repository:

```
  public interface ICustomertRepository {
    IQueryable<Customer> FindAllCustomers();
  }

  public class CustomerRepository : MvcApplication2.Models.ICustomerRepository {
    public IQueryable<Customer> FindAllCustomers() {
      return db.Customers;
    }
  }
```

And my HomeController has this:

```
  public ActionResult Index()
  {
    var query = customerRepository.FindAllCustomers();
    return View(query);
  }
```

But how can I access values in my View? I can see item.Adresses.Street/item.Adresses1.Street with Intellisense in Model but when I will try it, 
I get NullReferenceException:

```
<% foreach (var item in Model)
   { %>
<tr>
    <td>
        <%= Html.Encode(item.FirstName) %>
    </td>
    <td>
        <%= Html.Encode(item.Surname) %>
    </td>
    <td>
        <%= Html.Encode(item.Adresses.Street) %>
    </td>
    <td>
        <%= Html.Encode(item.Adresses1.Street) %>
    </td>
</tr>
<% } %>
```

I am completely lost. I tried to search everywhere but without any success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EF does not do automatic lazy loading.

You need to either manually load the related objects (not feasible for a multiple result set like your query), or instruct EF to include the desired properties for a whole query:

```
public IQueryable<Customer> FindAllCustomers() {
    return db.Customers.Include("Adresses").Include("Adresses1");
  }
```

You can find a comparison of how to do it between EF and LinqtoSQL (if you are used to it) in [this post](http://blogs.msdn.com/adonet/archive/2008/10/07/migrating-from-linq-to-sql-to-entity-framework-eager-loading.aspx). It will at least show you the EF syntax for that anyway.

Comment: Hi, looks like this is the "magic". I tried that and it seems to be working. But I have found another problem. When some Customer does not have AddressTemporary(Customer.AddressTemporaryID==Null), I will get that NullReferenceException too.

Comment: That makes sense. The binding algorithm tries to access the "Street" property on the "Addresses1" property, which returns a null reference. You should try to use something like  Html.Encode(item.Adresses1 == null ? "", item.Adresses1.Street) in your expression

Comment: Wow, it works like a charm now.   

 <%= Html.Encode(item.Addresses != null ? item.Addresses.Street : "")%>   

As I know myself, I will reach some another "breakpoint" soon, hehe.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that

```
 var query = customerRepository.FindAllCustomers();
```

works properly? Have you checked on the controller side that the query is in fact populated? You should write some unit tests, but at the very least, set a breakpoint on that line, and see if query gets populated correctly.

Comment: Hi, yes it is working correctly. When I remove that Addresses line in my View, data in View are shown correctly. It is possible that I made somewhere some typo while rewriting it because I have it written in my native language originally.

Answer (score 0):

Actually in your scenario where the `AddressId` and `Address1Id` are FKs in the table:

While the actual references (Address and Address1) are not loaded unless you either do an `Include()` or an explicit `AddressReference.Load().`

The actual FK value is loaded into the Entity into the EntityReference's EntityKey i.e.

```
addressID = item.AddressReference.EntityKey.EntityKeyValues[0].Value;
```

Hope this helps
Alex